# Geddy model / controller inheritance

Tags: node.js, geddy

Is it possible to make inheritnace with geddy model? I'm thinking like this:

*model/base.js*

```
module.exports = function(query, options){
 self = this;
 // some custom codes goes here that need to be use on some models
}
```

*model/model1.js*

```
util = require('util');
Base = require('./base');

Model1 = function(){
 this.defineProperties({ .... });

 ... and more
}
util.inherits(Model1, Base);
exports.Model1 = Model1;
```

and same with the controllers like  `baseFrontend.js` for the frontend and `baseBackend.js` for the backend controllers.

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is JavaScript, I don't think the term "inheritance" really applies.

It is certainly okay to mix-in shared methods into your models and controllers.

`geddy.mixin(Model1, Base);`

Comment: So how should I use `geddy.mixin` I can't find anything in the documentation. Thanks